# ASP.NET MVC count rows from YYYY-MM-DD to MM-YYYY

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So here is the thing, I am collecting details from the view, and based on the details *(which include ID, SiteName, Date, etc)*, I need to count the number of rows available in the same month & year from the provided `SiteCode` and `Date`.

My database table has an `ID`, `SiteCode`, and `Date` (YYYY-MM-DD)

The below thing on the controller can count on the same date, but I need the count rows in month-yyyy

```
public ActionResult CreateTT(tblTT fctt) 
{
    int countFuel = db.tblFuelTroubleTickets
                      .Where(x => x.SiteCode == fctt.SiteCode && 
                                  x.RequiredVisitDate == fctt.RequiredVisitDate).Count();
}
```

I have tried different approaches but couldn't understand how to parse etc

Answer (score 0):

Dates have no format, they're binary values, both in C# and all databases except SQLite. There's nothing to parse.

If you want execute a query for a specific date range you need to first calculate the start/end dates of that range, then filter your query using those dates.

```
var year=fctt.RequiredVisitDate.Year;
var month=fctt.RequiredVisitDate.Month;
var startInclusive=new DateTime(year, month, 1);
var endExclusive=startDate.AddMonts(1).Date;

var count = db.tblFuelTroubleTickets
              .Where(x => x.SiteCode == fctt.SiteCode 
                   && x.RequiredVisitDate >= startInclusive 
                   && x.RequiredVisitDate < endExclusive)
              .Count();
```

In this particular query there's no need to format dates. You can format the initial date or the year and month variables:

```
Console.WriteLine("The count in {0:MM-YYYY} is {1}",count,fctt.RequiredVisitDate);
```

You could also format the output in the `Select` operation:

```
var result=db.tblFuelTroubleTickets
             .Where(x => x.SiteCode == fctt.SiteCode 
                      && x.RequiredVisitDate >= startInclusive 
                      && x.RequiredVisitDate < endExclusive)
             .Select(t=> new { Date=fctt.RequiredVisitDate.ToString("MM-YYYY"),
                               Count=t.Count()})
             .First();
```

Comment: Perfect a little change and its working :-)